# Has the Twelve Demon Moons power levels been given by the author?

Tags: demon-slayer

I was watching a YouTube video and the Youtuber said the ranking of the 9 Pillars has been given by the author. Apparently it would be,

> 9. Insect Pillar
>  8. Serpent Pillar
>  7. Mist Pillar
>  6. Love Pillar
>  5. Water Pillar
>  4. Wind Pillar
>  3. Flame Pillar
>  2. Sound Pillar
>  1. Stone Pillar

How about the Twelve Demon Moons? Has the Twelve Demon Moons power levels been given by the author?

Comment: The Twelve demon moons have their ranking marked in their eye, if that is the rating you are looking for. I found the original [power levels for the pillars](https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/kimetsu-no-yaiba/images/3/31/2018-06-14-3-274x300.png/revision/latest?cb=20190821045702) the youtuber probably used, but I can't say my Japanese is good enough to read and thus determine what rating is used here exactly.

Comment: @Dimitrimx reverse-searching that image seems to hint about the official physical strength ranking based on *arm-wrestling* contest...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Their rankings are denoted by their numbers. Upper Moon 1 through 6 are the strongest 6 after Muzan arranged in the order of their numbers, then lower 6 stand in a similar fashion.

Here's some info from the manga:

> Upper moon 1 was annoyed that Upper moon 3 Akaza did not abide to the hierarchy of Upper moons. He suggested that if this bothers him so much, he can apply for a Blood battle against Upper Moon 2 to swap places implying the hierarchy is based on battle strength

This is what we can assume given the latest chapters:

> There are some demons with the potential to be one of the moons. As we see that Upper moon 6 (Daki and Gyutaro) and Upper moon 4 (Hantengu) were replaced in a matter of days following their deaths.